# Coin flip: what is the expectation of the n0. of coin flips to get a repeated pattern of 4 flips (overlaps allowed)?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Coin flip: what is the expectation of the n0. of coin flips to get any repeated pattern of 4 flips (overlaps allowed)?

16 Patterns , eg. HHHH, HHHT etc.

So HHHHH would constitute 2 repeated patterns of HHHH.

a) What is the expectation of the number of coin flips until a consecutive repeated pattern? eg HHTTHHTT is 8 coin flips, where the pattern HHTT is repeated

b) What is the expectation of the number coin flips when the pattern can be non consecutive?
HHTTTTHHTT is 10 coin flips?

My attempt at a)

The consecutive patterns are :
HHHHH
HHTH HTH, HTHH HTH, HTTH TTH
HHHT HHHT, HHTT HHTT, HTHT HTHT ,HTTT HTTT

the other 8 patterns are formed by swapping the Hs and Ts

Out of the 16 possible there are $2$ of length $5, 6$ of length $7, 8$ of length $8$.

so the probability of getting a consecutive pattern off the bat is $2((1/2)^5 + 3(1/2)^7+4(1/2)^8 = 9/64$

in an average length of $29/4$ , so the E(X)$ = 64/9*29/4 = 464/9$

I am not sure this is right for a)

Comment: It depends on the pattern!

Comment: @Math1000, I should have probably been clearer, the pattern is any string of 4, it is the number of flips until any pattern is repeated a) consecutively b) non consecutively